# Deferred Lighting | Point Lights Using Circles

Tags: opengl, 3d, game-engine, post-processing, deferred-rendering

I'm implementing a deferred lighting mechanism in my OpenGL graphics engine following [this](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial36/tutorial36.html) tutorial. It works fine, I don't get into trouble with that.

When it comes to the point lights, it says to render spheres around the lights to only pass those pixels throught the lighting shader, that might be affected by the light. There are some Issues with that method concerning cullface and camera position precisely explained [here](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial37/tutorial37.html). To solve those, the tutorial uses the stencil-test.

I doubt the efficiency of that method which leads me to my first Question:

#### Wouldn't it be much better to draw a circle representing the light-sphere?

A sphere always looks like a circle on the screen, no matter from which perspective you're lokking at it. The task would be to determine the screenposition and -scaling of the circle. This method would have 3 advantages:

- No cullface-issue
- No camereposition-in-lightsphere-issue
- Much more efficient (amount of vertices severely reduced + no stencil test)

**Are there any disadvantages using this technique?**

My second Question deals with implementing mentioned method. The circles' center position could be easily calculated as always:

```
vec4 screenpos = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
vec2 centerpoint = vec2(screenpos / screenpos.w);
```

But now **how to calculate the scaling of the resulting circle?**
It should be dependent on the distance (camera to light) and somehow the perspective view.

Comment: sphere will not look like a perfect circle if you use perspective projection, btw. You can make a quick drawing of what happens when you project sphere on a surface perspectively, to see that it in most cases won't be a circle.

Comment: You're right. Still, when multiplying the radius by 1.2 with a perspective angle of 45° , it would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that would work. The point of using spheres is they are used as *light volumes* and not just circles. We want to apply lighting to those polygons in the scene that are inside the light volume. As the scene is rendered, the depth buffer is written to. This data is used by the light volume render step to apply lighting correctly. If it were just a circle, you would have no way of knowing whether A and C should be illuminated or not, even if the circle was projected to a correct depth.

[image]

Comment: The point of deferred shading is to first render the scene into several textures holding the data for each pixel(position, color, normal...). Then, in the postprocessing, the **depthbuffer is set off** and the light components of all pixels are calculated. Circle or sphere, it doesn't matter which to use as long as the pixels are covered by them.

Comment: That's incorrect, depth buffer *write* is set off, but depth testing is still active, e.g.: `Configure the stencil operation for the front facing polygons to decrement the value in the stencil buffer when the depth test fails but to keep it unchanged when either depth test or stencil test succeed.` That means the depth buffer is read, but the values are not updated in the light volume step.

Comment: I know that's how they do it in the tutorial, to solve the cullface-issue. Nevertheless this isn't the case in my implementation. I'm not using the stencil-test. How Pavel Beliy mentioned, I could as well render a screen-filling planar quad. All pixels covered by that quad are passed throught the lighting shader, depth isn't tested.

Comment: Think about it like this - if you just light everything in the area of a screen-space circle, you're essentially casting a long cone of light into the scene, and lighting everything that's inside that cone. That's not what you want, because your point lights have a 3D position in the scene, and you want to illuminate objects *near that point*. If you just have a screen-space circle, you would end up illuminating things that are in front or behind the 3D location of the light source.

Comment: The key sentence is at the end of your first link (Tutorial 36): `The second problem is that the bounding sphere doesn't really bound the light and sometimes objects that are outside of it are also lit because the sphere covers them in screen space so we calculate lighting on them.` This is what you would be stuck with if you only used a circle.

Comment: If you look at the first picture of Tutorial 36, the spheres apply lighting to the background as well, even though there's nothing there! You can probably see why that's obviously incorrect - light should only be visible on surfaces. That's because the stencil buffer step, which will handle that, is not yet implemented there. And you can't do it with a circle.

Comment: The first picture of T. 36 is just a visualization of the bounding spheres. It isn't the actual lighting. However I must admit that you're right. With implementing the stencil test depth is tested, and that's a big advantage of bounding spheres + stencil test. Now I see why many people use that technique.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read the whole thing, but i think i understand general idea of this method.

1. Won't help much. You will still have issues if you move the camera so that the circle will be behind the near plane - in this case none of the fragments will be generated, and the light will "disappear"
2. Lights described in the article will have a sharp falloff - understandably so, since sphere or circle will have sharp border. I wouldn-t call it point lightning...
3. For me this looks like premature optimization... I would certainly just be rendering whole screenquad and do the shading almost as usual, with no special cases to worry about. Don't forget that all the manipulations with opengl state and additional draw operations will also introduce overhead, and it is not clear which one will outscale the other here.
4. You forgot to do perspective division here
5. The simplest way to calculate scaling - transform a point on the surface of sphere to screen coords, and calculate vector length. It mst be a point on the border in screen space, obviously.

Comment: 1. You're right, I forgot about that. In such a case you would have to render the screen-quad.

Comment: 2. The attenuation factor on the border of the lightsphere is that low, it's close to nothing. You wouldn't see that.

Comment: 3. A screen-quad for each light? With, lets say, 20 lights? sounds expansive in relation to passing the pixels effected by the light.

Comment: 4. Again, you're right. Actually I didn't know about that, as the vertex shader does it automatically. I'll edit that

Comment: 5. Understood. But how to determine the point on the border in screen space?

Comment: 3: no not for each light... just have an uniform array of say up to 20 light coordinates and do the shading calculation in a for loop

Comment: 5: it's really simple and involves just a bit of trigonometry. The idea is to build a triangle between camera position, sphere center, and a point on a surface that we'll need to find. This triangle is right-angled, with 90° angle at the touching point(eye ray is tangent to the surface there). We know 2 sides of the triangle, which is enough to calculate all its angles. Then you build a vector from sphere's center, which has length of this sphere's radius and lies at the correct angle to the camera-sphere center vector.

Comment: 3: That's another way to do it (passing all lights at once to the shader). For some, that might be better, in my situation seperate light-passing will be better.

Comment: 5: Awesome, that sounds logic. I'd upvote your awnser, but don't have enough reppoints. It isn't an actual solution yet. Are you going to edit it with this discussion? What's the common way of doing this?